# Accessing Django Modules from a Django subdirectory

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up some documentation for a Django project. The documentation lives in a folder called docs within the project root:

```
  project-root/
    doc/
  app1/
  app2/
  app3/
  urls/
```

The problem is I'm writing an extension to the documentation that lives in the doc/ folder. When I generate the documentation, I run the extension outside of the context of Django (just as a script). In the extension, I need to access an object in the project's url's file.

But when I try to import project.urls, I get an import error.

How can I get access to project-root/urls when I'm running a script in project-root/doc/extension.py that isn't run through Django?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your Django environment with this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your_project/")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "yourproject.settings"
```